# Arduino running at 8MHz with external crystal

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to use my Atmega328P in 8MHz, but I noticed that the internal clock is not as accurate and cause problems in my application. To add an external crystal 8MHz I do like the image below or 22pF capacitors are only necessary when I use a 16MHz crystal?

[image]

Comment: **You need to use the capacitors** as this helps the signal generated by the crystal to be stable. If you do not use them, it will be worse than the internal clock basically.

Comment: You need to use **the correct capacitors**. The capacitors to choose depend on the crystal. **Read the datasheet**.

Comment: If you want to keep your componenet count down- then you may want to consider a resonator instead of using crystals and capacitors

Comment: @qwerty10 Resonators aren't that much better than the internal RC clock source. Yes, they can be faster, but no more accurate. Personally I don't use either. I use MEMS clock chips now - usually the ASEMB range from ABRACON.

Comment: @Majenko My interpretation of the question is  seemed to  impliy that the OP wanted to use as few components as possible so I suggested using a resonator. In my experience Ive found resonators to be accurate. But it would depends on the situation of course how accurate the clock pulse is to be required which only the OP really knows. Yes you can use a clock chip too-sometimes found in old epson printers-which is what you seem to be referring to.

Comment: @qwerty10 I highly doubt that old Epson printers used MEMS® clock chips. They are a very recent invention.

Comment: @Majenko Thats why I said _seem_ to be referring to. Maybe its more accurate if I said the following. You can get clock chips or subcircuits in Epson usb printers (that can be reused)  and maybe there made by ABRACON. It a long time since I looked inside epson printer to fix it so Im not totally  sure.

Comment: [This](http://majenko.co.uk/assets/BoardComponents.png) is a board I am at the prototyping stage with now. The MEMS® clock chip is the small one immediately south-west of the main chip. I think you are referring to the old crystal oscillator modules - the big metal 4-pin cans.

Comment: What you trying to make overall? I recall there was a small clock chip in the printers-it had maybe up to 12 pins. It had its own battery supply in the printer control circuit. I dont recall if it used an external  crystal. If I can remember all the details I'll let you know. Basically it was a way to save money by reusing that part of the printer circuit.

Comment: That sounds like either a clock generator chip (needs a crystal with it) or a clock management chip (takes a clock from elsewhere and creates other clocks from it). Still, 12 pins is 8 too many...

Comment: It was a self contained clock circuit (if you cut it out from the PCB) yes the number of pins was up to 12, so could have been less-simply dont recall now as it was so long ago. What are the other chip names in your circuit?

Comment: I could understand your circuit design if you explained it all. Part names and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you require the capacitors, and the capacitors have to be the right value for your crystal.

The datasheet will specify a *load capacitance* which you use in the following formula:

```
C1 = C2 = 2(CL - C_STRAY)
```

That is, the *load capacitance* of the crystal, minus the stray capacitance from your circuit (as long as your traces are short that is negligible and can be largely ignored unless you have very very tight timing requirements) multiplied by 2.

So for 22pF capacitors it is safe to assume that the crystal that is with them has a load capacitance of 11pF.

So check the datasheet for the load capacitance (it should be very prominent) and select the correct capacitors accordingly.

If you want to do away with the capacitors and your timing requirements aren't that precise you may get away with a ceramic resonator which doesn't require capacitors.

Another option is to use a MEMS® clock chip which generates a stable clock signal at a pre-set frequency. While this doesn't require capacitors for the clock signal it does still require a decoupling capacitor on the power supply for it, but of course that doesn't affect the timing of the clock signal, so precise selection of a specific value isn't needed.

Comment: When would stray capacitance or stray inductance be significant if the 22pf capacitance was made from a number of capicitors connected in a combination of series and parallel to make up a 22pf capacitance? E.g. use two 44pf capacitors in series to make 22pf-and two 11pf capacitors for another 22pf-but it could be a lot more complicated than that-such as using lower values e.g. 1pf capacitors.

Comment: This crystal here has 18pF capacitance, then I need two 36pF capacitors. Is correct? http://br.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ABRACON/ABLS-8000MHZ-B2-T/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsBj6bBr9Q9aUe%252bp9Tek3UMgyOb46u0oQg%3d

Comment: Yep, that is correct.

Comment: it would be interesting to know a good answer to the question I made in the comment above.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the question.

Comment: I would guess it to be yes there is a threshold where it becomes significant for my question in the comment. I got the idea for the question when trying to make a value for a capacitance from other capacitors.

Comment: It all depends *what you are doing* and *how important the timing is* to whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: And my question in the comment was referring to values such as - C_STRAY

Comment: I am sorry, you have completely lost me now. Go back to shining lasers at each other to try and make a yellow dot in mid air.

Comment: That's a Majenko style, end of this conversation then.